Grafana variable interpolation
I have an "environment" template variable. And I want to somehow use it to interpolate $namespace that I have in my JSON. So if I selected prod, then $namespace would use "test1" and if shared is selected then $namespace would use "test2". I don't want to use another template variable for namespace.
The issue is that I am using Grafana version 4.6. I am not allowed to update the version. So what is a way to accomplish this without using key : value within the template variable? I ask this because when I attempt to do
prod: test1, shared: test2

Those are the options prod: test1 and shared: test2 instead of just prod and shared.
So I am assuming key/value is not introduced yet in the 4.6 version.

I think colon supposed to have spaces on both sides, like prod : test. No idea if it is supported by 4.6
